# Phabricator - my own application, router and 404 error

Tags: php, phabricator

I created basic application based on phabricator/src/applications/uiexample. In phabricator/src/extensions/ I added fallowing controller but routing is not working for me:

```
<?php

final class PhabricatorGanttApplication extends PhabricatorApplication {

  public function getBaseURI() {
    return '/gantt/';
  }

  public function getShortDescription() {
    return pht('Gantt chart');
  }

  public function getName() {
    return pht('Gantt chart');
  }

  public function getIcon() {
    return 'fa-area-chart';
  }

  public function getTitleGlyph() {
    return "\xE2\x8F\x9A";
  }

  public function getFlavorText() {
    return pht('Gantt chart for your tasks.');
  }

  public function getRoutes() {
    return array(
      '/gantt/' => array(
        '' => 'PhabricatorGanttRenderController',
        'view/(?P<class>[^/]+)/' => 'PhabricatorGanttRenderController',
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Do I have to do anything else to make routing work?

Does exist any tutorials showing how to create applications for a phabricator?

Answer (score 0):

If your not using developer mode then you would need to restart the phabricator daemons in order to see your application

You may also need to ensure that your phabricator config has prototype applications turned on (which is probably off by default)

Assuming you have a class classed PhabricatorGanttRenderController this looks correct.